# Force facebook share title

Tags: html, facebook, wordpress

I have a wordpress website with a few simple pages and a facebook share button in the header. As it is now, facebook uses the wordpress page name as the title for the share, but I'd like it to use the html title instead (or just specify my own). How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin. It allows you to add open graph tags on page or post basis or default settings for your site.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/open-graph-protocol-in-posts-and-pages/

Comment: I put the desired title into the plugin for all my pages, but the share still shows the wordpress page name as it's title. I also used the facebook debugger to reset.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `<meta property>` tags in your HTML.  Notice the indented lines:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>Your Title</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Your Title" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

You have a wide variety of properties to choose from: [Open Graph Protocol Official Documentation](https://ogp.me/).  Ultimately, this is just a problem of using the right HTML.